# how to get the encoded data by json_encode in the java script file

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, json

I am encoding file data using `json_encode` and this is what I get when I send the encoded data in Javascript:

[image]

This is my php code (using codeigniter to upload a file):

```
$file_info = $this->upload->data();
echo json_encode($file_info);
```

and I use the data in my javascript file:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
      alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
}
```

How can I use file_name or other strings as they are encoded?!

for example how can I use:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
  alert('The file name is: ' + file_name);
}
```

Comment: `alert ('The file name is: ' + data.file_name)` ?

Comment: If you want to use the json data in javascrip, why you are uploading them and parsing with php? Do data.file_name?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` to see what it is? Usually it's an object.

Comment: @Grim & wumm I did it, but i got: The file name is: undefined

Comment: @JackCole, no I didn't. because I'm new to Javascript and I really don't know what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 variables in your response. To see what each one is when your code is executed, use console.log().

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
    console.log('\n"data" variable:')
    console.log(data);
    console.log('"file" variable:')
    console.log(file);
    console.log('\n"response" variable:')
    console.log(response);
}
```

Now open up your javascript log (F12 in Chrome, Shift+F5 I think in firefox). The Json data should have been converted into an object. If it's in its json form, add `JSON.parse(data)`.

Objects are the backbone of javascript. To select information in an object named `data`, you use `data.property`. So `data.file_name` should return "83274983279843.jpg", `data.type` would return the type, etc.

Edit: So after discussion in chat the issue was you didn't parse the JSON. Also I incorrectly told you to reverse the variable order.

Here is the fixed code:

```
'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) { 
    data = JSON.parse(data) 
    alert('The file : ' + data.file_type); 
}
```

Comment: This is what I have: 
`Object`
`client_name: "15971_609999215698807_1118915796_n.jpg"`
`file_ext: ".jpg"`
`file_name: "5341fdd4b1d89985bf7e23a37f7494c9.jpg"`
....

Comment: The 3 variables, `(file, data, response)`, do not care what they are named. Only what order they are in. So `file` actually contains your data, `data` is your file information. Change it to `(data, file, response)` and it should work.

Comment: Once you change that, `data.client_name` should return `"15971_609999215698807_1118915796_n.jpg"`, and `data.file_ext` should return `".jpg"`

Comment: I changed the console.log information so when you do it now, it's more clear what each variable is. The variable containing all the information should be called `Object {~~~~~~~~}`. What's the name of that variable?

Comment: `"data" variable: 
{"file_name":"edb7e52b545ca6fccb7f0a8d83e7df1b.jpg","file_type":"application\/octet-stream","raw_name":"edb7e52b545ca6fccb7f0a8d83e7df1b","orig_name":"935823_163724623815235_533051709_n.jpg","client_name":"935823_163724623815235_533051709_n.jpg","file_ext":".jpg","file_size":39.98,"is_image":false,"image_width":"","image_height":"","image_type":"","image_size_str":""}
"file" variable:
Object {creationdate: Tue J ...`

Comment: I copied your object into my console log, and I was able to access it's contents fine. Are you trying to use `data` outside the function then? That's the only reason I could see `data.file_name` not working.

Comment: what do you mean by outside the function?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35549/discussion-between-jack-cole-and-afshin)